# Saving an image from Android Processing Sketch

Tags: java, android, processing

I'm trying to save an image from my Android Processing sketch but I get an error. How can I save my sketch to an image file in the user's phone gallery?

```
public void draw(){
        beginShape();
        for (int i=0; i<d.length; i++){
            d[i].maison();

            int stroke1 = (int) random(255);
            int stroke2 = (int) random(255);
            int stroke3 = (int) random(255);

            stroke(stroke1, stroke2, stroke3);
            noFill();
            vertex(d[i].x , d[i].y);
        }
        endShape(CLOSE);

        UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
        save(idOne + ".tga");

    }
```

**Error:**

> 09-15 23:47:25.939 23317-23389/tutorials.androidstudio.fragmentsv3
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
>       Process: tutorials.androidstudio.fragmentsv3, PID: 23317
>                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File
>   android.app.Activity.getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference
>                    at processing.core.PApplet.sketchPath(Unknown Source)
>                    at processing.core.PApplet.savePath(Unknown Source)
>                    at processing.core.PApplet.save(Unknown Source)
>                    at tutorials.androidstudio.fragmentsv3.Sketch$override.draw(Sketch.java:74)
>                    at tutorials.androidstudio.fragmentsv3.Sketch$override.access$dispatch(Sketch.java)
>                    at tutorials.androidstudio.fragmentsv3.Sketch.draw(Sketch.java:0)
>                    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
>                    at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)
>                    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the save directory. Normally, the way your code is, Processing would save the file to a "data" folder within your project directory but that doesn't work in Android Mode. Also, I never really tried it but Android might have a class which can return you certain directories of a device without you looking for them such as Images, Downloads, etc. You should see the Google Developer pages about that.